# Tcl StarKit versus SQLite database as a program?

Tags: sqlite, tcl

I was reading [this paper](https://www.tcl.tk/community/tcl2004/Papers/D.RichardHipp/drh.html) from 2004 by Dr. Hipp and am interested in the section entitled *Database as Program*. However, I am confused by how this relates to the Tcl StarKits.  I'm writing far beyond my skill level in asking this question; so, the terms may not be fully accurate.

If I understand correctly, StarKits are packaged together such that the Tcl interpreter is included in the StarKit; and a user that does not have Tcl installed on their machine can still run the StarKit package as a single executable file.

The issue with this, at least for my purposes, is that a SQLite database included in the StarKit has to be extracted from it to be used; it cannot be used from within the VFS.

Thus, the idea of a database as a program appears interesting but I don't understand a couple things.

A. One is that it appears that the database is not the full program, in that a separate Tcl script must be included to retrieve the main script from the database to get the thing running, albeit it would likely be quite a small script.

B. Another is that it appears that one could not include the Tcl interpreter in the database itself, because it would be needed to run the initial Tcl script.  Therefore, the user must have Tcl installed on their machine to run the database program.

C. Another, is whether the program is to be included in the same database as the rest of the data or separately? If not separately and there is a lot of data, would that not make updates more difficult.

My program is really just a database library of information that Tcl primarily searches and displays by acting as a very simple local server.

**1. Am I understanding these two correctly?**

**2. What would be the most important decision points in determining which option to choose?**

**3. Are there other options?**

I'm not at the point to package it together yet, but would like to build the rest of it with the packaging in mind. Thank you for any guidance you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starkits are based on a simpler database technology than SQLite, Metakit, which is effectively a key-value store. It's also a bit older, and there was early focus with it on how to make single-file applications (by effectively attaching a small filesystem to a Tcl executable that it can pull scripts and other resources out of). The only really tricky bit with it was that it needed a special piece of code (`sdx`) to build, which meant that it was fine for building applications but not for the Tcl/Tk core libraries themselves.

SQLite is a pretty much full embeddable database engine that was designed from the word go to work with Tcl; the enormous majority of aspects to it that are considered weird are *actually* very non-weird when coming to it from Tcl.

The technology for mounting a SQLite database as a filesystem (well, it'd have to be a specific schema I guess) is nothing like as well known as Starkits.

---

> 1. Am I understanding these two correctly?
> 2. What would be the most important decision points in determining which option to choose?

The main thing you are missing is that the one option doesn't really lock out the other. In particular, you can make a build of Tcl that includes both the SQLite library and your startup script statically built (short scripts become an embedded C string).

If you want a *runtime-modifiable* database, you have to have that separate from the executable on at least one major platform (Windows) because the OS locks executing files to be read-only. You might work around this by including a read-only copy of the database file in your embedded filesystem and copying it out the first time the application is run. The copied out DB file can then be opened as normal by the `sqlite3` package. (The SQLite engine can't work directly with databases in an embedded filesystem; it needs too much low-level filesystem access in order to handle things to do with transactions.)

I wouldn't choose Metakit for my database option. Choosing a Starkit is more sensible, at least until Tcl 8.7 or 9.0 come out (they're currently in moderately advanced alpha); those have built-in for embeddable filesystems (based on ZIP archives, to make the bootstrapping problem much easier).

Note that Tcl's embedded filesystems work with not just `open` and `source`, but also `load`; you can include native C code and expect things to Just Work. (They tend to work better when the C code is built as a stubbed library so that it can use C API profiles instead of binding to a specific revision of a dependency.)

> 3. Are there other options?

The easiest is to not worry too much about going to a single-file distribution. A small archive of files is almost as easy to use, especially if they're designed to be run from any location (i.e., you locate everything else with respect to the startup script). That has the advantage of allowing you to have multiple active databases; that sometimes makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I consider this to be really just a summary with many aspects left out, but going deeper needs much more specifics to start from. Also, this answer is already far longer than I expected…

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write this response.  It is very helpful.  I'm glad you mentioned the use of multiple active databases because I was trying to figure out how to handle accepting user input, such as notes on the content in the library, and make the information easily shareable between users. I wanted to use more than one database, separating the library from the users data, but thought I read that wasn't a good idea. Glad to read here that it is okay.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the questions, but I can comment on TCL and SQLite.

I write graphic utils at my work (Windows) and as a hobby using TCL almost exclusively because it's easy and I'm not a professional. Most of these utils keep a SQLite database. SQLite is really just a format, and runs server less. All SQLite commands and interactions with the actual dB file can be done within the TCL script. (require package sqlite3) After creating the executables, the end users need neither TCL/Wish nor sqlite3 on their computers.

I hope I'm not way off base here, and that some of that may have helped.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. This is, in part, what I am interested in, except that I want to write to the database also from within the Tcl program; and was considering structuring the program as described in that article.

Comment: The database is created from within the TCL script, and all db read/write is also done from within the script.

Comment: And actually, I see no real benefit in using SQLite as a platform. It's kind of like arch linux, guys get a chubby when they build their system, but was it necessary or even useful in the long run?